# Bitwise right shift operator >> didn't worked as intended

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I am writing a code to find the number of ones in  binary representation of a number

here is the code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int n,tNum,count = 0;
    cin >> n;
    tNum = n;
    while(tNum > 0)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int bit = getBit(n,i);// get bit
        if (bit == 1)
        {
        count++;
        }
        tNum >> 1;
        i++;
    }
    cout << count << endl;
}
```

Above code gives an endless loop and tNum didn't change its value
I didn't understand where I am doing wrong

Comment: Define and initialize `i` outside of the loop.

Comment: `tNum >> 1` doesn't change `tNum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Bitwise right shift operator >> didn't worked as intended*

The bitwise right shift operator `>>` is working as intended but you are not storing the result of `>>` operator anywhere. This expression

```
tNum >> 1;
```

will right shift the value of `tNum` by `1` but the result of this expression is unused.

Use `>>=` operator instead of `>>`. It should be:

```
        tNum >>= 1;
```

This is same as `tNum = tNum >> 1`.

Another problem in your code:

This

```
getBit(n,i);
```

will give the `0`<sup>th</sup> bit of `n` (as the `i` is initialised with `0` in every iteration) and which is going to be same for every iteration. Instead, you should get the `0`<sup>th</sup> bit of `tNum` as you are using shift operator on `tNum` below in your code. Also, you don't need `i` at all, just remove it. The statement should be:

```
int bit = getBit(tNum, 0);// get 0th bit
```

One more important point, the result of right shift `>>` of a negative number is implementation defined. May, you should use `unsigned int` type for `n` and `tNum`.

You can do:

```
int main (void)
{
    unsigned int n, tNum;
    int count = 0;

    cin >> n;
    tNum = n;
    while(tNum > 0)
    {
        int bit = getBit(tNum, 0);// get bit
        // You can also do
        // int bit = tNum & 1;

        if (bit == 1)
        {
            count++;
        }
        tNum >>= 1;
    }
    cout << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note: There is scope of improvement in the implementation of your code. I am leaving it up to you to identify those improvements and make respective changes in your code.

Comment: Ok, Now I got this. Thanks you very much for your support. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `int i = 0;` at the start of the loop so `i++` doesn't do anything useful.  Also, you don't update `tNum`.  Consider using a `for()` loop instead which implies moving the initialization outside the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; tNum > 0; i++) {
   ...
   tNum >>= 1;
}
```

As you only use `n` in the call to `getBit()` you could refactor it to eliminate `tNum`. Prefer using unsigned values when shifting.  It's not clear (to me) if a bit count of a negative value would count the sign bit.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    unsigned n;
    cin >> n;
    unsigned count = 0;
    while(n) {
        if(n & 0x1) count++;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    cout << count << endl;
}
```

Finally, modern processors usually have an instruction for this (popcnt) which you compiler might wrap for you or you can access it via an intrinsic (there are many versions available).

Answer (score 0):

You either don't need the `i` or you don't need to shift `tNum`, decide which one.

For example:

```
    int count = 0;
    while(tNum > 0)
    {
        count += getBit(n,0);
        tNum >>= 1;
    }
```